# Issue with DOT in ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I want to use a select to show/hide an input.

Here is my fiddle, but it doesn´t work. I think, the reason will be the dot in the ng-model?!

**HTML**

```
<div>
<select ng-options="t.name as t.name for t in fields" ng-model="rule.field">
</select>
<input ng-show="rule.field==2" type="text">
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('QueryBuilderCtrl', ['$scope',
function ($scope) {

    $scope.fields = [{
                    id: 1, name : 'Title'
                }, {
                    id: 2, name : 'Abstract'
                }, {
                    id: 3, name : 'Age'
                }, {
                    id: 4, name : 'Date'
                }, {
                    id: 5, name : 'In Progress'
                }];

}
]);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgf8dybe/)

Thank your tips and help

Answer (score 1):

```
<select ng-options="t.name as t.name for t in fields" ng-model="rule.field">
```

That means that when you select an option in the select box, `rule.field` will have the `name` of the selected option (i.e. `'Title'`, or `'Abstract'`, or ...). And there is no way that a name is equal to 2.

Use `ng-options="t.id as t.name for t in fields"`.

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
<select ng-options="t.id as t.name for t in fields" ng-model="rule.field">
```